# Trying to get laravel to a online server

Tags: php, laravel, server, bootstrapper

I am trying to get a laravel project online on my server.

What I've done:

- Copy all files to `public_html` folder the copy the public contents to public_html root too.
- Ran the `composer install` and update which are executed successfully.

But when I try to access the server I get the following error:

```
Warning: require_once(DIR/bootstrap/start.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/ivaware/public_html/index.php on line 36

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'DIR/bootstrap/start.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/ivaware/public_html/index.php on line 36
```

I don't have this file `"start.php"`.

I tried to deleted vendor folder and composer.lock file and then generate again this files with `composer install` but no luck.

What can I try/do ?

Comment: Read the "Configuration -> Public Directory" section of the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation

Comment: can you mention which version of laravel are you using?

Comment: Im using laravel 5.4

Answer (score 0):

in your index.php .. you need to change these lines from :

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

to

```
require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Comment: Why? This would be done only if he changed the Laravel folder structure to one that matchs this. Also would be necessary to change another path references in the code

Comment: he copied all files to public_html & public contents to public_html also .. so my answer matches his file structure i think .. 

he said : 
What I've done:

Copy all files to public_html folder the copy the public contents to public_html root too.

Comment: Humm, did not understand like this, I've thought he had copied all files, but with the Laravel's folders structure, makes sense